# How to add Twitter embed to Quill js?

Tags: javascript, twitter, embed, quill

I have a website for a journalist that needs to embed tweets in his texts, I am currently using this code to paste the twitter blockquote in the text but it does not seems to work, I guess its something related to quill removing the class="twitter-tweet" when displaying it on the editor, (I already enabled access to Twitter requests in the cookies and using dangerously paste HTML should not be a problem i guess, since the only user is the owner of the website). Any help would be of great value :)

the relevant part of my script:

```
  <script>
            document.cookie = "cookieName=cookieValue; SameSite=None; Secure";
            let delta;
            var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
                theme: 'snow',
                sanitize: false,
                modules: {
                    toolbar: [
                        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'image', 'video'],
                        [{ size: ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }]
                    ]
                },
                attributes: {
                    blockquote: ''
                },
                formats: {
                    image: 'image-size-limited' // Apply custom CSS class to images
                }
            });

            const twitterHtml = document.getElementById('twitterHtml');
            const addTweetButton = document.getElementById('addTweetButton');
            addTweetButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const tweet = twitterHtml.value;

                // Extract the non-script portion of the tweet HTML
                const tweetWithoutScripts = tweet.replace(/<script.*?>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/g, '');

                // Append the non-script portion to the Quill editor
                quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(tweetWithoutScripts);

                // Add the Twitter widget script to your document
                const twitterScript = document.createElement('script');
                twitterScript.src = 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                twitterScript.charset = 'utf-8';
                twitterScript.async = true;

                // Handle script onload or other event if needed
                twitterScript.onload = function () {
                    // The Twitter script has loaded, you can perform additional actions if required
                };

                // Append the Twitter script to the document
                document.body.appendChild(twitterScript);

                twitterHtml.value = '';
            });
```

[what shows up in the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o6NS.png)
[what shows up in the inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbc0f.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue myself recently while building my text editor. Quill seems to sanitize any `script` tags before inserting text into the editor, which is why only the blockquote from the original embed code is shown.

I found two Quill modules/examples that seem to find a slight workaround to this

**quill-tweet**
https://github.com/contentco/quill-tweet

Solution from a user and the subsequent CodePen example

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/2567

https://codepen.io/DmitrySkripkin/pen/oOBLdo

I'm sure you can customize this a bit more to fit your needs. I hope this helps your issue!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).